# how to pass values from a formgroup to another formgroup realtime as a two way data binding in a reactive form?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic4, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have 2 `FormGroups`, `orderForm` and `parcelForm` in a page and `parcelForm` is dynamically generated in a `FormArray`. `parcelForm` has `FormControl` like `net_weight`, `gross_weight` and `OrderForm` has `FormControl` i.e `total_net_weight` and `total_gross_weight`. I want to two bind the values of the `parcelForm` FormControl `net_weight` and `gross_weight` so that whenever the user dynamically add a `parcelForm` and enter the values for the `FormControl` `net_weight` and `gross_weight` it will reflect the `total_net_weight` and `total_gross_weight` FormControl of the `orderForm`. I have tried the `patchValue` function like `this.parcelForm.get('parcels').patchValue([iterator, 'net_weight'])` as well as `this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([iterator, 'net_weight']).value` but with no success. 
This is the `new-order.page.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from 'src/app/models/order.model';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { OrderService } from 'src/app/services/order.service';
import { NavController, ModalController, ActionSheetController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-order',
  templateUrl: './new-order.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-order.page.scss'],
})
export class NewOrderPage implements OnInit {
  @Output() formChange = new EventEmitter();
  pageTitle: string;
  orders: Order[];
  order: Order;
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  parcelForm: FormGroup;
  error;

  number_of_parcel = 0;
  total_net_weight = 0;
  total_gross_weight= 0;

  constructor(
    private orderService: OrderService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllDestionation();
    this.orderService.getAllOrders()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.orders = data
      );
    this.orderForm = new FormGroup({

      number_of_parcel: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
      }),
      total_net_weight: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
      }),
      total_gross_weight: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
      })
    });

    this.parcelForm = new FormGroup({
      parcels: new FormArray([])
    });

    this.formChange.emit(this.parcelForm);
  }



  onSubmit() {
    this.mapFormValuesToOrderModel();
    if (this.order.id) {
      this.orderService.updateOrder(this.order).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.goBack();
        },
        (err: any) => this.error = err
      );
    } else {
      this.orderService.createOrder(this.order).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.orders.push(data);
          this.goBack();
        },
        (err: any) => this.error = err);
    }
  }




  goBack(): void {
    this.navController.navigateRoot('/members/menu/tabs/orders');
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log(this.orderForm);
  }


  parcels(): FormArray {
    return this.parcelForm.get('parcels') as FormArray;
  }

  newParcelFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      net_weight: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
      }),
      gross_weight: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
      }),
    });
  }

  addParcelButtonClick() {
    this.parcels().push(this.newParcelFormGroup());
    this.number_of_parcel++;

    let num = [];
    let iterator = 0;
    for (iterator = 0; iterator < this.number_of_parcel; iterator++) {
      console.log(this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([iterator, 'net_weight']).valueChanges);

      num.push(Number(this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([iterator, 'net_weight']).value));

    }

    console.log(num);

  }

  removeParcel(parcelIndex: number) {
    this.parcels().removeAt(parcelIndex);
    this.number_of_parcel--;
  }

  onChanges(): void {
    console.log('parcelForm > onChanges', this.parcelForm.value);
    this.parcelForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.formChange.emit(this.parcelForm);
    });
  }

}
```

This is the `new-order.page.html`:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-title>{{pageTitle}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size-md="8" offset-md="2">

      <form [formGroup]="orderForm">        
        <ion-item *ngIf="hideTemplate">
          <ion-label position="fixed">No. of Parcels</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" autofocus formControlName="number_of_parcel">{{number_of_parcel}}</ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-label
          *ngIf="orderForm.get('number_of_parcel').hasError('required') && orderForm.get('number_of_parcel').touched">
          Name can't be empty!
        </ion-label>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="fixed">Total Net Weight</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" autofocus formControlName="total_net_weight">{{total_net_weight}}</ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-label
          *ngIf="orderForm.get('total_net_weight').hasError('required') && orderForm.get('total_net_weight').touched">
          Name can't be empty!
        </ion-label>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="fixed">Total Gross Weight</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" autofocus formControlName="total_gross_weight"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-label
          *ngIf="orderForm.get('total_gross_weight').hasError('required') && orderForm.get('total_gross_weight').touched">
          Name can't be empty!
        </ion-label>
      </form>
      <br>
      <br>

      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="4" offset="10">
          <ion-button color="success" (click)="addParcelButtonClick()">
            <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>Add Parcel
          </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <form [formGroup]="parcelForm">
        <div formArrayName="parcels">
          <div *ngFor="let parcel of parcels().controls; index as parcelIndex;">
            <div [formGroupName]="parcelIndex">
              Parcel {{parcelIndex + 1}}:
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="floating">Net Weight</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="net_weight"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-label *ngIf="parcel.get('net_weight').hasError('required') && parcel.get('net_weight').touched">
                Remarks can't be empty!
              </ion-label>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="floating">Gross Weight</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="gross_weight"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-label *ngIf="parcel.get('gross_weight').hasError('required') && parcel.get('gross_weight').touched">
                Remarks can't be empty!
              </ion-label>

              <br>
              <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="4" offset="10">
                  <ion-button color="danger" (click)="removeParcel(parcelIndex)">Remove <ion-icon name="trash-outline">
                    </ion-icon>
                  </ion-button>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>


    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: you should detect changes on parcels instead of the parcelForm

like this.parcelForm.get('parcels').onValueChanges(changes => {
 //recalculate total 
});

Comment: @nightingale2k1 Ok, I have tried this:

this.parcelForm.get('parcels').valueChanges.subscribe(
      data => this.total_net_weight += data[this.iterator]['net_weight'],

    );

but if I add 100 in the net_weight then It adds 200 to the total. I think the iteration is the problem. I think I am very close but don't know what is the error.

Comment: actually you need to substract the previous value and then add new value. 
but since we dont have old value, it is easier to iterate the whole array and get the total/

var fa = this.parcelForm.get('parcels') as FormArray ; 
var temp = fa.getRawValues();

// iterate temp to get the total and the patch value to total.

Comment: @nightingale2k1 I am getting undefined every time using a iterator to get the net_weight. Can you please check?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12540 
This is the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the values the following way:

```
this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([this.iterator, 'net_weight']).valueChanges.subscribe(
      data => this.total_net_weight += data
    );
```

I didn't had to make any changes in the frontend.

This is my `addParcelButtonClick()` function ended up looking like

```
  async addParcelButtonClick() {
    this.parcels().push(this.newParcelFormGroup());
    this.iterator = this.number_of_parcel;
    let gross_weight = 0;

    this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([this.iterator, 'net_weight']).valueChanges.subscribe(
      data => this.total_net_weight += data
    );
    this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([this.iterator, 'gross_weight']).valueChanges.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.total_gross_weight += data;
        gross_weight = data;
      }
    );


    this.getOrderFormValues();
    this.number_of_parcel++;

  }
```

This is the `getOrderFormValues()` function:

```
getOrderFormValues() {
    this.orderForm.setValue({
      total_net_weight: this.total_net_weight,
      total_gross_weight: this.total_gross_weight
    });
  }
```

And this is the `removeParcel` function:

```
async removeParcel(parcelIndex: number) {
    // this.iterator = this.number_of_parcel;
    if (this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([parcelIndex, 'net_weight'])) {
      this.total_net_weight -= await this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([parcelIndex, 'net_weight']).value;
      this.total_gross_weight -= await this.parcelForm.get('parcels').get([parcelIndex, 'gross_weight']).value;

    }
    this.parcels().removeAt(parcelIndex);
    this.number_of_parcel--;
    this.getOrderFormValues();
  }
```